# Using IF condition to copy either one cell or another

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm creating a list of sorts where I have two columns, one with an expected value the next with an actual value based on information taken from a dropdown box, so three possible variables. I would like a third column to copy another cell based on the outcome i.e. the copied cell is red with text "failed" if the values do not match and a green cell with text "passed" if the values match.

I have been pointed at conditional formatting but I'm not sure it can do something this complex.

Comment: That all sounds quite do-able. One note: you talk about "copying" a cell, but it sounds like you just need a formula that compares values and returns either "passed" or "failed". Applying conditional formatting to that cell is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

With the following columns and data
A1 `1`
B1 `=C1`
C1 `5`

try this in D1 :

```
=if(C1<B1, "OK", "NOT OK")
```

or

```
=if(C1<B1, C1, B1)
```

After this you can apply conditional formatting on your D columns where the condition should be: if value = OK than background green, else red

Conditional formatting is done via you excel menu, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Dk1JoL_Pe4) is a little tutorial on how to do it.

Of course you can change the condition inside the if, here i use a bigger or smaller evaluation.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting based on a formula.

So highlight C1, or whatever your column range is, and add conditional formatting. Then select to base the criteria off a formula.

For rule 1, do A1=B1 (Don't lock if you wish to drag down) and format as Green fill.
For rule 2, do A1<>B1, and format as Red fill.

To add actual text inside the cell, do if(A1=B1,"Pass","Fail")

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns are A and B and C the one to be formatted, Conditional Formatting can do the text and the fill "in one hit" (for each colour) provided there is something in the ColumnC cells to start with - say `=CHAR(1)`:

Select ColumnC HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=A1<>B1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red Fill and for Number, Custom `;;;"failed"`, OK, OK.

Then repeat with:

```
=AND(A1<>"",A1=B1)
```

and selecting green fill and Custom Number format: `;;;"passed"`, OK, OK.